# Using a database in android activity

Tags: android, sqlite, onclick, oncreate

I am learning how to use a sql database in an Android activity. I am learning from [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/). I have an activity in which I use the database handler, from the tutorial. 
I make a declaration of the variable inside of activity class.

```
DatabaseHandler db;
```

In the oncreate method I create a new DatabaseHandler object:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

I want to use the database after a button has been clicked. So I use the connection in the onClick method, but I get a null pointer exception unless I create a new object in the onclick. Why is that, with different type of objects I can declare variables like I did in this example.

The constructor of the DatabaseHandler is:

```
 public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

The super being SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the null exception because you're instantiating incorrectly. you declared your db a field, but then instantiated a **different** object `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);` <-- as a local variable. Thus your onClick only has access to the uninstantiated field. to fix you need to replace what you have with this in your oncreate.

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

or if the onClick is in onCreate, by applying the final modifier. (and removing the field object)

Comment: @mango how to use `db = new DatabaseHandler(this);` out of any activity such as custom class for work with database?